# A memory leak in a simple Python C-extension

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I have some code similar to the one below. That code leaks, and I don't know why. The  thing that leaks is a simple creation of a Python class' instance inside a C code. The function I use to check the leak is `create_n_times` that's defined below and just creates new Python instances and derefrences them in a loop.

This is not an MWE per-se, but part of an example. To make it easier to understand, what the code does is:

1. The Python code defines the dataclass and registers it into the C-extension using `set_ip_settings_type`.
2. Then, a C-extension function `create_n_times` is called and that function creates and destroys `n` instances of the Python dataclass.

Can anyone help?

In Python:

```py
import c_api

@dataclass
class IpSettings:
    ip: str
    port: int
    dhcp: bool

c_api.set_ip_settings_type(IpSettings)
c_api.generate_n_times(100000)
```

In C++ I have the following code that's compiled into a Python extension called `c_api` (it's a part of that library's definition):

```cpp
#include <Python.h>

// ... Other functions including a "PyInit" function

extern "C" {
    
PyObject* ip_settings_type = NULL;
PyObject* set_ip_settings_type(PyObject* tp)
{
    Py_XDECREF(ip_settings_type);
    Py_INCREF(tp);
    ip_settings_type = tp;
    return Py_None;
}

PyObject* create_n_times(PyObject* n)
{
   long n_ = PyLong_AsLong(n);
   for (int i = 0; i < n_ ++i)
   {
       PyObject* factory_object = ip_settings_type;

       PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(3);
       PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("123.123.123.123"));
       PyTuple_SetItem(args, 1, PyLong_FromUnsignedLong(1231));
       PyTuple_SetItem(args, 2, Py_False);

       PyObject* obj = PyObject_CallObject(factory_object, args);
       Py_DECREF(obj);
   }

    return Py_None;
}

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a Py_DECREF(args) inside the for loop?

Comment: @Neil I thought so too, but when I add it I get memory-related errors... Let me check it again.

Comment: I don't understand, why the C++ tag?

Comment: @Neil Yes... By adding `Py_DECREF(args);` after `Py_DECREF(obj);` I get the error `free(): invalid pointer`, but not right away - after over 10K iterations.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It started as a C++ question, but I reduced it to C. It's more of Python-API question anyway. I'll remove that tag.

Comment: PyTuple_SetItem steals the reference to the supplied object, but Py_False is a single object. When the args tuple is destroyed, is the reference count for Py_False getting mangled? Try using PyBool_FromLong(0) to create a new reference to Py_False, like the other two SetItems. (see https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bool.html)

Comment: @Neil Great job!!! This was the issue. Post it as an answer and I'll confirm it! For some reason I thought `Py_False` was a macro... That's the last time I listen to ChatGPT LOL (it generated the code). Thank you very much!

Comment: You might have the same issue with the reference counts for `return Py_None` (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/none.html). It looks like it should use `Py_RETURN_NONE` instead.

Comment: Yeah, In my code I actually use `Py_INCREF` on `Py_None` before returning it, but you are correct. That might also be possible for `Py_True`/`Py_False`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PyTuple_SetItem` steals the reference to the supplied object, but `Py_False` is a single object. When the args tuple is destroyed, the reference count for Py_False isgetting mangled.

Use `PyBool_FromLong(0)` to create a new reference to `Py_False`, like the other two calls to `PyTuple_SetItem`. (see docs.python.org/3/c-api/bool.html)

Comment: ... or `Py_INCREF(Py_False)` before assigning it to the tuple should do it, too, and would be more idiomatic.  Either way, this is just the sort of thing that should be well documented in the code, lest some future dev attempt to "fix" it.